# How should I test this class using rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have created a service object that creates new interactions. When an interaction is created, this kicks off logic to generate a lead. Leads are generated differently based on interaction_type.

See code below:

```
class InteractionCreation

  def initialize params = {}
    @interaction = Interaction.new(params)    
  end

  def call
    if interaction.save
      generate_lead
    end

    return interaction
  end

  private

  def interaction
    @interaction
  end

  def generate_lead
    LeadGeneration.new(interaction).call
  end
end
```

I have tried a few things, but I am not sure how much I should be testing. It's easy to test whether an interaction is generated or not, but should I be doing anything regarding the lead that is created by LeadGeneration. I have tried to minimize the size of the public interface and only testing that right now. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do at least this:

```
describe InteractionCreation do

  let(:interaction) { double :interaction }
  let(:params)      { double :params }
  let(:action)      { described_class.new(params).call }
  let(:lead)        { double(:lead) }

  before do
    Interaction.should_receive(:new).with(params).and_return interaction
    LeadGeneration.stub(:new).and_return(lead)
  end

  it 'doesnt call Lead Generation when save ko' do
    interaction.stub(:save).and_return false
    lead.should_not_receive :call

    action
  end

  it 'calls Lead Generation when save ok' do
    interaction.stub(:save).and_return true
    lead.should_receive :call

    action
  end

end
```

Maybe return value should be check too, in this case, add another spec :)

Comment: To add to this ... is there a difference between LeadGeneration.stub(:new).and_return(lead) and LeadGeneration.any_instance.stub(:new).and_return(lead) I am not sure exactly when this should be used, but from my understanding the two lines above are one in the same. Also from my reading using any_instance is not necessarily best practice. Does it make much of a difference? Can I stub out calls like you have here at a class level?

Comment: using any_instance, you dont have access to the specific instance we are stubbing and on which we have a `should_receive` expectation

Answer (score 0):

You can check the public methods like 'initialize' and 'call' using rspec. Check if the initialize method assigns the attributes correctly. for the 'interaction' method, you can check if 'generate_lead' is called if the interaction is saved.